# Create a presentation from Org mode

Tags: org-mode, init-file

All I'm trying to do is to create a slideshow presentation from Org mode.
As everyone does, I [googled](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ppt%20with%20org%20mode) to get a few links.
I followed [this link](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/non-beamer-presentations.html) to write Non-Beamer presentations, as I thought presenting over a web browser would be a cool thing to do (maximum portability).
I chose to go with

> org-html5presentation
>
> Is an Exporter of Org-mode documents to HTML5 slide show presentations. (see gist.github.com/509761 for code and usage information)

Even though the instructions are simple as follows:

1. First of all, check your Org-mode version. Note: This library has
   been tested on Org-mode 8.2.5h. M-x org-version
2. Get org-html5presentation.el. For example,
   git clone https://github.com/kinjo/org-html5presentation.el.git \
   ~/org-html5presentation.el
3. Add following to ~/.emacs.d/init.el and reboot emacs.
   (add-to-list 'load-path "~/org-html5presentation.el")
   (require 'ox-html5presentation)

I did not know how to do **Step-2** above
I copy pasted the *org-html5presentation.el* lisp code into file with name *org-html5presentation.el* and saved it in some folder and added the path as requested in **Step-3**.

Nothing has worked so far. I get the error **"Cannot open load file :org-html5presentation"**

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load-path` is the list of directories, not files.  If you want to add this file, use in `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

```
(load-file "~/org-html5presentation.el")
(require 'ox-html5presentation)
```

Better way is to put the file into `~/emacs.d/org-html5presentation/org-html5presentation.el` and then put the `~/.emacs.d/org-html5presentation/` into `load-path` writing in `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/org-html5presentation/")
(require 'ox-html5presentation)
```

or load just one file with

```
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/org-html5presentation/org-html5presentation.el")
(require 'ox-html5presentation)
```

Comment: your answer *load-path is the list of directories, not files* was bang on. Thanks for the excellent answer

Comment: even though the error is gone - i'm unable to get the org mode file contents as html presentation - Any ideas why?

Comment: It's the point of another question.  But it needs more information about the problem: what are in the output of the program, messages, etc.